# Nginx how to set proxy pass using map based on the host and location

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

Currently I setting proxy pass dynamicaly using map directive. Now I would like for a specifc location /dcs/ I would like to set a different proxy pass rather than one mentioned through map.conf and proxy_pass.map. Is there a way to say use different map for a specific location /dcs/.

Should just use If stantement like if host is dev-api.mysite.com then set proxypass to http://abcdef.com. Is this the only option.

MySite.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name ~^(api|dev-api|staging-api)\.mysite\.com$;

    location / {

        proxy_set_header Cookie "";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0; includeSubDomains" always;
        proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/headers.inc;
    }

    location /dcs/ {
        set $proxy_host $host;
        set $proxy_pass Set-different-host based of dev,staging,prod;
        proxy_set_header Cookie "";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0; includeSubDomains" always;
        proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/headers.inc;
    }

}
```

maps.conf

```
map $host $proxy_pass {
    hostnames;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy_pass.map;
}
```

proxy_pass.map

```
# mysite.com

api.mysite.com                        myst.plat:8080;

staging-api.mysite.com                staging.myst.plat:8081;

dev-api.mysite.com                    dev.plat:8080;
```

headers.inc

```
proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$proxy_pass;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $real_scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme $real_scheme;
proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-GeoIP-Country-Code $geoip_country_code;
proxy_set_header X-Site-Id $site_id;
add_header X-Cache-Time $date_gmt;
add_header X-Cache-Date $upstream_http_date;
add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
# add_header X-Site-Id $site_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use several chained `map` blocks:

```
map $host $proxy_by_host {
    hostnames;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy_pass.map;
}

map $uri $proxy_pass {
    ~^/dcs/    abcdef.com;
    default    $proxy_by_host;
}
```

**Update**

Looks like I slightly misunderstood your question, to use two different `map` blocks depending on request URI, use something like

```
map $host $proxy_by_host {
    hostnames;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy_pass.map;
}
map $host $dcs_proxy_by_host {
    hostnames;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/dcs_proxy_pass.map;
}
map $uri $proxy_pass {
    ~^/dcs/    $dcs_proxy_by_host;
    default    $proxy_by_host;
}
```

This way if all the other parameters for your locations are equal, you can use only one `location / { ... }` for all requests.